# Where does Firefox get the HSTS information from?

Tags: firefox, ssl, certificate, https

I have a local server serving HTTPS using a self-signed certificate. It does not serve http. The certificate is issued with cn=host1.subdomain1.domain1. The server is reachable under name host2, too.
If I open https://host2 I get warnings, but I can define an exception for the certificate and can access the servers content. The server does not and did never return an HSTS header.
If I access the server via https://host1.subdomain1.domain1, Firefox gives a HSTS warning and doesn't allow an exception.
It is possible that servers at domain1 or subdomain1.domain1 delivered HSTS headers. Possibly they applied to sub-domains, too.

But: Even after clearing history and about:permissions entries, the behaviour is the same. So, where does the HSTS information come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The HSTS header can instruct the browser to include subdomains by using `includeSubDomains`. Browsers may also contain a preloaded list of domains which use HSTS.

- A site can use the following to specify HSTS with six-month duration and including subdomains:

  ```
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains
  ```
- The effect of doing this is exactly as described in your question. The key here is the `includeSubDomains` at the end of the header line.
- Note that current versions of most major browsers maintain [a internal list of websites](https://hstspreload.appspot.com/) which are known to use HSTS and can therefore demand HTTPS connectivity even when connecting to a particular domain for the first time. **See also: [OWASP on HTTPS Strict Transport Security](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security).**